# When I touch in tableview How to get all values Back in tableview in search

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios7, xcode7

I trying to search a particular name in an array, It is working well, But I want to cancel search by touching in other place in tableview, How to do that.

I trying to search a particular name in an array, It is working well, But I want to cancel search by touching in other place in tableview, How to do that.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

//    arr1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Raj",@"Ramu",@"Abdul",@"Kavitha",@"Abi",@"Abinesh",@"Gobi",@"Giri",@"Gayathri",@"Ramesh",@"Thiru",@"Sri",@"Siva",@"Senthil",@"Kumar",@"Rajkumar",@"Raman",@"Karthik",@"Kanna",@"Kamal",@"Ramya",@"Somu",@"Sankar",@"Murali",@"Muthu",@"Murugan",@"Nandha",@"Kamal", nil];
//    NSLog(@"%@",arr1);

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.92/Abdul/Json/Json5.txt"];
    NSURLRequest *req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    conn=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];

    if(conn)
    {
        webdata =[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
        NSLog(@"Connection Success");
    }
    //[tabvw reloadData];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    [webdata setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    [webdata appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"%@",@"Fail");
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    jsonarr=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webdata options:0 error:nil];
    if (jsonarr> 0)
    {
        [tabvw reloadData];
    }
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (isfiltered)
    {
        return [filterarr count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [jsonarr count];
    }
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myid"];
    if (cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"myid"];
    }
    if (isfiltered ) {
        dic =[filterarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text=[dic objectForKey:@"Name"];
    }
    else
    {
        dic =[jsonarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text=[dic objectForKey:@"Name"];
    }

    return cell;
}

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
    NSPredicate *pred =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Name contains[c]%@",searchText];

    filterarr = [jsonarr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];

    NSLog(@"%@",filterarr);

    isfiltered=YES;
    [tabvw reloadData]; 
}

-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    [sbar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's try this and check output,

**ViewDidLoad**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(refreshData:)];
tapGesture.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

#pragma mark Gesture delegate
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
if (touch.view == self.view)
    return YES;
    return NO;
}

- (IBAction)refreshData:(id)sender
{
    isfiltered=NO;
    [tabvw reloadData]; 
}
```

Comment: @VyTcdc as per your requirement you can change "self.view" into "tableview" etc etc..

Comment: could you tell me when I want to do the same while I click the (x) cross button available in search.